# integer array static initialization

Tags: java, arrays, static

Which two code fragments correctly create and initialize a static array of int
elements? (Choose two.)

A.

```
static final int[] a = { 100,200 };
```

B.

```
static final int[] a;
static { a=new int[2]; a[0]=100; a[1]=200; }
```

C.

```
static final int[] a = new int[2]{ 100,200 };
```

D.

```
static final int[] a;
static void init() { a = new int[3]; a[0]=100; a[1]=200; }
```

Answer: A, B

here even D seems true, can anyone let me know why D is false.

Comment: This is not valid Scheme, Ruby, Python or LISP code. Please format your code and specify the language/framework you are using.

Comment: You might need to change the title so that it actually summarises the question ..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The correct answers are 1 and 2 (or A and B with your notation), and an also correct solution would be:

```
static final int[] a = new int[]{ 100,200 };
```

Solution D doesn't initalize the array automatically, as the class gets loaded by the runtime. It just defines a static method (init), which you have to call before using the array field.

Answer (score 6):

D defines a static method for initialising `a` but does not actually call it. Thus, `a` remains uninitialised unless someone explicitly calls the `init` method.

As other answers have pointed out: D shouldn't even compile because it attempts to assign a value to the `final` variable `a`. I guess that's a much more correct explanation. Nevertheless, even if `a` was not final D would still not work without extra code.

I assume the `new int[3]` in D is a typo? The other three all attempt to create an array of length 2.

Comment: ya u r really correct.I found the answer i Scjp .ur explanation is correct.dont mind about the votes

Answer (score 3):

D (4) is false, because a) **`a` is final and you cannot assign it in `init`**; b) there is no guarantee that `init` will be called; c) `init` doesn't set the third element;

Comment: Why in the world was this down-voted? This answer is entirely correct.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think it is not entirely correct. c) is incorrect because `new int[3]` initializes all the elements to zero as far as I can remember. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sergey you aren't wrong, I mentioned it as aside comment, since I think (as mentioned somewhere) that `new int[3];` should be `int[2];`. The main reason that makes D false is that `a` is final.

Comment: sergey c is incorrect.But not because of ur reason.The actual reason u can either inialise an array and dnt mention the dimension,or u can create a specific dimension for an array and inialise it later.But u can not initialise an array and simultaneously initialise it.Anyhow thanks for ur participation.The same was mentioned was by Ratna

Answer (score 1):

for  snippet C You cannot give dimensions ( Size ) while initializing
for snippet  D you should initialize final variable. It cannot be initialized later.

Answer (score 0):

final variables should be initialized before constructor call completes. Since "static void init()" is a method & it will not run before constructor, final variables won't be initialized. Hence it is an compile time error.