# instantiation of static array in Android / Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, static

In the sample of code shown below I am using the "new" keyword to instantiate a string array.  however instantiation is for objects only,  is it wrong to do this since the c[] array is static?  is there another way to do this, or should i use the "new" to instantiate it as if it were an object?

```
public class SmallTank {

static String tableString = " ";

static String c[];
static String d[];
static String p;

public SmallTank(){

    c = new String[66];
    d = new String[29];

    // initialize string array
    for(int v = 0; v<66; v++ ){
        c[v] = null; 
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449935/integer-array-static-initialization

Comment: On a side-note using static here is bad practise, if possible, you should avoid it :)

Comment: if your size remain fix then its fine otherwise create exception.

Comment: If you want to create a new string array for which you are certain that you would put 66 string objects, then "new" is good, in my opinion. But if the string objects vary then try using ArrayList or Vector. You should initialize the static variables inside static reference, which in case can be a static initialization block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is an object. So **`c` is an object**, and it being static does not change that.

What it does mean though, is that **every object** of `SmallTank` will end up **overwriting `c` and `d`.**

*I think* what you want is to do [static initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

add

```
static {
    c = new String[66];
    d = new String[29];

    // initialize string array
    for(int v = 0; v<66; v++ ){
        c[v] = null; 
    }
}
```

And remove those calls from the constructor.

This will initialize `c` and `d` only once.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this code `c[v] = null;` , by default all the elements of an array of reference is `null`. Array is an object , hence you use `new` to instantiate it. Don't do it inside the constructor , you can directly instantiate it where you declare.

```
static String c[] = new String[66];
```

This creates a static array object, hence all the instances of the class share this object.You can create array in other ways too :

```
static String[] c = {"a","b","c"};
static String[] c = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays are objects. Therefore they are created with `new`.

Only the reference to this objects is bound to the `class` by the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In java every `array` is an `object`. Does not matter array is the static reference.
 For initialization purpose you can use static initializer block

```
  static {

        c = new String[66];
        d = new String[29];

        }
```

It will load first only one time when the class load in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that the array is initialised everytime you create an instance of SmallTank.  Perhaps this is what you want but usually, a static initialiser is the correct approach:

```
public class SmallTank {

    static String tableString = " ";

    static String c[] = new String[66];
    static String d[] = new String[29];
    static String p;

    static {
        // initialize string array
        for(int v = 0; v<66; v++ ){
            c[v] = null; 
        }
```

This will initialise the array once, when the class is first loaded - usually the first time you create any instance of it.

As others have pointed out, initialising to null is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the static modifier is:

You can think of a 'static' method or field as if it were declared outside the class definition. In other words

There is only one 'copy' of a static field/method.
Static fields/methods cannot access non-static fields/methods.

So what you'll want is :

```
static String c[] = new String[66];
static String d[] = new String[29];
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the arrays when you declare them, not in the constructor.

```
public class SmallTank {
    static String c[] = new String[66];
    static String d[] = new String[99];
...
}
```

It is legal to do this in the constructor, but the point of using a static field is to share it between instances. In your case, the arrays would be reset every time you create a new instance of `SmallTank`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects in Java. Therefore they are created with `new` keyword.

And there is only one 'copy' of a static field/method.Means only one static variable is there in class and it is always shared between all methods of class. Static fields/methods cannot access non-static fields/methods.

So you can modify your code as:

```
static String c[] = new String[66];
static String d[] = new String[29];
```

You can also refer this docs:
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html