# Reservation application, disable button when condition reached

Tags: java

I want to create a simple reservation application, like when you want to book movie ticket online, except this is a much simplified version.

I have a class names reservation with 8 toggle buttons and 1 button, the user will get to input number of seat they want to book in another class, let's just say 4.
In reservation, after the user choose 4 seats, the rest of the toggle button will be disabled to prevent user from choosing more seats. The user will then click the save button, and the data will then be inputted in the Database. Next time when another user open reservation, **all of the toggle buttons will be re-enabled** except those 4 seats previous user has booked earlier, obviously.
Everything is working so far except the part that i bold.

Here's my code :

```
private static final JToggleButton[] btn = new JToggleButton[8];
private int totalrow, a;
java.sql.Connection connection = null;
Statement statement4 = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {  // This is where i load the information that has been saved in the database before.                                   
    
    try {
        
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:
        statement4 = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement4.executeQuery("SELECT reservationid, seatno, validator FROM reservation WHERE reservationid = '" + time.id + "'");
        
        String seatno, validator, rsid, id;
        
        btn[0] = seat1;
        btn[1] = seat2;
        btn[2] = seat3;
        btn[3] = seat4;
        btn[4] = seat5;
        btn[5] = seat6;
        btn[6] = seat7;
        btn[7] = seat8;
        
        int i = 0;
        while(resultSet.next()){
            seatno = resultSet.getString("seatno");
            validator = resultSet.getString("validator");
            rsid = resultSet.getString("reservationid");
            
            if(seatno.equals(btn[i].getText()) && validator.equals("reserved")){ //checking if seat i is reserved
                btn[i].setSelected(true);
            }
            else{
                btn[i].setSelected(false);
            }
            i++;
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(seat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}   

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { // This actionlistener is used to count, if User has choose 4 seats, the code will disable the rest of the button
    
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Project","root","root");
        statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        
        btn[0] = seat1;
        btn[1] = seat2;
        btn[2] = seat3;
        btn[3] = seat4;
        btn[4] = seat5;
        btn[5] = seat6;
        btn[6] = seat7;
        btn[7] = seat8;
        
        a = 0;
        for(JToggleButton btns : btn){
            if (btns.isSelected()){
                a++;
                System.out.println(a);
                
                if (! btns.isSelected()){
                    System.out.println(a);
                    a--;
                }
            }  
        }
        
        for(JToggleButton btns : btn){
            if (a >= Integer.parseInt(BookingUI.passenger)){ // This is number of Passenger taken from another class. In this case is 4.
                if(! btns.isSelected()){
                    btns.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            
            else{
                btns.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(seat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Regarding my title, based on my current code and logic, it might not be possible to re-enable the toggle button. So the better way to do it might be to use another logic to disable the toggle button instead.

In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUKxZ.png), seat 1,4,5,8 are chosen by the user. And the rest of the buttons are disabled

Comment: let me know if i didn't explain it clearly

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of the user interface you have build for a better understandment

Comment: yeah sure, could you let me know how to insert screenshot in the comment section / my post. haven't done it before

Comment: it's easy. just click to edit your own question and in the edit window you will see several buttons for edit options like to Bolt, Underlined, insert link and a icon to insert a image. When you click it you will get a popup window to upload the image :)

Comment: yep done. also included a little bit information, i wonder why it's not showing up

Comment: it's because you still new to the community and need more reputation points to gain ability to upload images :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a long implementation, it's difficult to answer with a code solution. There for I will mention my suggestion here.

You have to declare your **JToggleButton Array** like this `btn = new JToggleButton[8];` in a public static context where every class could access it. And when the user reserved a seat you should save the data to DB (or keep in the program memroy, eg : HashMap) on which user reserved the which seat.

After that when you loading the data from the Database you should loop through and get the booked seats which previously inserted and then by accessing that predefined **JToggleButton Array** and set each booked seat by doing this `btns[i].setEnabled(false);` (i for the booked index of the seat).
Hope this helps

Comment: I don't really get it, what's the difference between your suggestion with what i am doing now ? About the JToggleButton Array, I've declared it as public, although i don't show it in my post. But assigning it can't be done in public as far as i know.

Comment: I assume you know about the static keyword in the java. By defining JToggleButtons public static you can access it from anywhere and get any data.Do not define your JToggleButtons  inside a method. define it at class level but as a public static

Comment: i've edited my code in the post. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: partially yes. But you haven't add the static keyword to make it static. refer this link to get familiar with static https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449935/integer-array-static-initialization?rq=1

Comment: cool, that's new to me, thanks. Back to your suggestion though, you haven't answered my question

Comment: Glad to hear you learnt a new thing from me. :D first of all you have to backup what you already done so far before you try out this. (it's a good practise to back up). after that you have to change your source code to access static array other than the array in the method. Let me know when you did it.

Comment: updated the code, check it out. Wonder if i could initialize value of the array after i define it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176125/discussion-between-rahal-kanishka-and-kevin-guswanto).

Comment: since chatting long on a answer is not nice , I have initiated a private chat window. please follow the above link